# Trigger not working, can't figure out why

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am using  SQL server 2005 and when create a trigger I get the following error:

**the code**

```
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.dublicator 
   ON  dbo.PLACE_ORDER
   FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ADAPT_DR.DEBTS(CLIENT_CODE,CLIENT_NAME,CHARGES)

END
GO
```

When I execute I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   dublicator, Line 17 Incorrect syntax
>   near the keyword 'END'.

I have tried solving it but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a trigger, I assume the values going into that second table will be from the insert.  Answers stating use of `VALUES` are valid SQL Syntax, but not what you're looking for.  You will want to use the `inserted` magic table.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ADAPT_DR.DEBTS(CLIENT_CODE,CLIENT_NAME,CHARGES) 
SELECT CLIENT_CODE, CLIENT_NAME, CHARGES
FROM inserted
```

This assumes the column names are the same in both tables.  Please respond if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your `insert` statement is wrong - you're saying insert into the table `debts` but not telling it what to insert.  My suggestions is to read up and get some basic SQL knowledge (select, insert, update).

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement is incomplete. It should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ADAPT_DR.DEBTS(CLIENT_CODE,CLIENT_NAME,CHARGES) 
                       values (value1, value2, value3)
```

providing the values with in the corresponding data types of the columns specified.

Comment: Never use the values clause in a trigger.

Comment: Point taken. Makes sense in *most* cases. Beware of generalizations, though. There are no gold immutable rules.

Comment: SQL Server truggers are batch based and thus the values clause is not appropriate unless that changes which is is not likely to.